# Compress user's sentence after positions are given

Tags: python, compression, python-3.4, code-completion

I done this code below and had some help with the compression part. The code is not working and I don't understand how to fix it. In my class we are still beginners so i'm not too good. Also when its asking the user for a sentence, why is it stating as b'_' instead of Please enter a sentence?

```
import gzip
File = open('Users Sentence.txt', 'w') 
Sentence = input(b"Please input a sentence ")                                                                
print (Sentence)                                                                                            
varNameIn = Sentence.encode('utf8')
Lower = Sentence.lower()                                                                                    
Splitsentence = Lower.split()                                                                                                                                                              

Userfile = File.write(Sentence)                                                                             
varNameIn = Splitsentence 
varNameOut = gzip.compress(varNameIn)
print(varNameOut)

varNameDecon = gzip.decompress(varNameOut)
print(varNameDecon.decode('utf-8'))

positions = {Splitsentence:index for index, Splitsentence in reversed(list(enumerate(Splitsentence, 1)))}   
fileposition = (' '.join(str(positions.get(word)) for word in Splitsentence))
print (fileposition)                                                                                        
Userfile = File.write(fileposition)                                                                         
File.close()
```

it gives me this error message and I don't understand it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\USER-PC\Users\user\Documents\homework\CW Computing\2.py", line 11, in <module>
    varNameOut = gzip.compress(varNameIn)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\gzip.py", line 624, in compress
    f.write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\gzip.py", line 343, in write
    self.crc = zlib.crc32(data, self.crc) & 0xffffffff
TypeError: 'list' does not support the buffer interface
```

Thanks.

Comment: Wild guess: you can't compress a list. Try compressing something else, such as a string.

Comment: I think you can only compress [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes)-like objects, though the docs are a little unclear

Comment: You might want to combine `pickle` with `gzip` to compress a `list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code with my annotations:

```
Sentence = input(b"Please input a sentence ") # Sentence is type str
print (Sentence)
varNameIn = Sentence.encode('utf8') # not used
Lower = Sentence.lower() # Lower is type str
Splitsentence = Lower.split() Splitsentence is a list of str objects
Userfile = File.write(Sentence) # Userfile = number of chars written (??)
varNameIn = Splitsentence # varNameIn is a list of str objects
varNameOut = gzip.compress(varNameIn) # attempting to compress a list
```

You need to rethink what/why you wish to do data compression ...